# Get the corner value of dienantion array in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement

I have a dimension array of integers from 1 to 25 which has 5 columns and 5 rows, and my code below will print the cross value which are 1, 7, 13, 19, 25.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int w[][] = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                 { 6, 7, 8, 9,10},
                 {11,12,13,14,15},
                 {16,17,18,19,20},
                 {21,22,23,24,25}};


    for(int i = 0 ;i< w.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int j=0; j< w.length ;j++)
            if(i== j){
        System.out.print(w[i][j]+"\t"); }}


}
```

I need a way to print the value which is below the cross line of `1,7,13,19,25`  will be work in any of numbers of rows and columns that mean will print in my array `6,11,12,16,17,18,21,22,23,24` how can I do that?

Please see the value which want to print below:

[image]

Comment: Try to identify the common pattern in all the indices of the numbers you want to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int w[][] = {
     {1,2,3,4,5},
     {6,7,8,9,10},
     {11,12,13,14,15}
    ,{16,17,18,19,20}
    ,{21,22,23,24,25}};

    for(int i = 0 ;i< w.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int j=0; j< w.length ;j++)
            if(i!=0&&i== j){

                for(int k=0;k<j;k++){
                    System.out.print(w[i][k]+"\t"); 

                }
            }
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
6   

11  12  

16  17  18  

21  22  23  24
```

Comment: i get this  reault but i need the result it will be 6,11,12,16,17,18,21,22,23,24

Answer (score 1):

First of all to print the cross line you don't need two loops. If you want to print only when i=j just make one loop:

```
 for(int i = 0 ;i< w.length ; i++)
     System.out.print(w[i][i]+"\t");  // Prints [1,1], [2,2] etc.
```

For the second task you will need two loops - one will loop the row and the second one columns in the row:

```
 for(int i = 0 ;i< w.length ; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)            // Loop each row to the middle -1
     System.out.print(w[i][j]+"\t");  //This should do what you want ;)
```

Comment: yeah the solution is still the same and will work for any NxN array.

Comment: can you get the solution in simple way bro

Comment: I think I have? It is pretty simple like that ;) 2 rows